# How do I block Gmail with the Self-Control App?

Tags: firefox, gmail, blocking, selfcontrol

I've been able to block Google.com, including Google Calendar, but I can't block Gmail in Firefox, no matter what I enter (mail.google.com, https://mail.google.com, the exact address of the account, etc.).  How do I block Gmail with Self-Control?  This may very well be a Firefox issue; it's hard to tell for sure.

I'm running OS 10.9 and Firefox 25.0.1.

Comment: does it work as expected with other browsers?  Which version of SelfControl are you using?  Has it ever worked as expected for you?

Answer (score 1):

Try blocking "api.google.com". This should block any web applications that might be circumventing SelfControl's blacklist.

EDIT: Removed period from inside of quotation marks so as not to confuse.